# readline(): I cannot display string

Tags: python

I am somehow lost! Anybody has a hint why the check_date string is not displayed in the output?

Thanks!
M

```
with open(LASTPULL,"r") as f:
  check_date = f.readline()

if check_date == date:
  print "\nNo new data. Pulled today already.\n"
  exit()
else:
  print "\nNew data found!\n"
  print "LASTPULL Date : ", check_date
  print "Actual Date   : ", date
```

Output:

```
New data found!

LASTPULL Date :  
Actual Date   :  2013-07-11
```

Comment: Please show us the file.

Comment: What is the value of `check_date`? Are you sure you aren't reading in an empty string?

Comment: the string seems to be '\n' as his print statement has a comma and the output still breaks the line as hinted by gnibbler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_date` should be the first line *including the newline*.

The only way to not have a newline in the output is for the file to be a single line with no newline.

Apparently the line is just whitespace (or possibly empty which this exact output would suggest).

You could try

```
print "LASTPULL Date : ", repr(check_date)
```

to better see what's going on.

It could be that `LASTPULL` isn't where you think it is. Double check for that zero length file.